# Do I need to delete pointer in stack, which is created in heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

```
int *createInt()
{
   int *a = new int;
   return a;
}

int main()
{
   int *x = createInt();
   *x = 10;
   cout << *x << '\n';
   delete x; // do I need this?
   return 0;
}
```

DO I need delete x? If i don't, will it cause a memory leak problem?

Comment: Anything you dynamically allocate you also delete.

Comment: Side note: Consider automating the process with a [smart pointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Answers: yes and yes.

Comment: Practical consideration: On a modern system, when the program exits the leaked memory will be reclaimed, so in a trivial program with a short runtime it is unlikely that you will notice the effects of a small leak. Mind you, if you go out of your way, for example the trivial program is a small loop allocating and leaking large quantities of memory, you'll see the leak eventually. Thanks to virtual memory and smart memory management, it might be long after your PC would have run out of RAM.

Comment: Every `new` should have a balancing `delete`. **BUT** I you should prefer alternative techniques were this is done for you automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear confused about the distinction between a pointer and the pointed at object.  `a` and `x` are pointers. Think of a piece of paper with a party address written on it.

`int *a = new int;` allocates a new object on the heap and assigns the address to the pointer `a`. This is like starting a party at a house, and then writing the address on a paper named `a`.

`return a;` returns the pointer to the caller. This is like handing the address-paper to the person that told you to start a party.

`*x = 10;` accesses the object, and modifies it. This is like going to the address on the paper, and passing around silly hats, you've changed it to a costume party.

`delete x; // do I need this?` Yes, you need to delete the object that you allocated.  This says "end the party at the address on this paper".

---

Other questions:

`what if I don't delete memory?` Then the party continues forever, and nobody else can party at that address ever again because the first party is still going.

`what if I delete the memory twice?` Ending a party twice makes no sense. Nothing might happen. Or it might burn down. Or it might be different each time.

`what if I use the pointer after deleting it?` Going to a party that ended makes no sense. Maybe nothing happens. Or maybe someone replaced the house with a Military base, and you're trespassing and get arrested. Or it might be different each time.

`what if I reassign the pointer without deleting?` If you erase the paper and write a new address on it, that doesn't do anything to the party. Except that you probably won't ever find it again, and the party continues forever.

`I was told that members of classes are destroyed when the class is destroyed. Does that delete the object?` No, burning the piece of paper with the address on it doesn't end the party.

Comment: Yes, I was confused about the pointer and object itself. The explanation using paper and party make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
delete x;
```

does not delete the pointer x itself. It deletes the dynamically allocated memory pointed to by the pointer x

```
int *a = new int;

//...

int *x = createInt();
```

After this statement

```
delete x;
```

the pointer x will be alive but will have an invalid value. As the pointer itself has automatic storage duration then it will be destroyed automatically after the end of the block scope where it is defined.

You should always delete dynamically allocated memory to avoid a memory leak.